# What's the best place to fork to create token-2022 with hook transfer function

Tags: token-2022

I have been trying to create a token-2022 via other forks or through Solana library, not sure what's the best way as I am a beginner just looking for end goals not go through the process of learning a new set of language besides basics.

What would be the best possible path to create one with set extensions or is there already a platform which has completed this.

Thank you